# Lift existentials in Coq

Tags: coq

Can this lemma be proven in Coq ?

```
Lemma liftExists : forall (P : nat -> nat -> Prop),
  (forall n:nat, exists p:nat, P n p)
  -> exists (f : nat -> nat), forall n:nat, P n (f n).
```

The simple `destruct` does not compile, because we cannot eliminate the object `exists p:nat, P n p` in sort `Prop`, to produce the function `f` in sort `Set`.

If Coq cannot prove this lemma, then what is the meaning of `forall n:nat, exists p:nat, P n p` ? In constructive mathematics it would mean the existence of the function `f`, but I have the impression that we will never see this function `f` in Coq, not even in sort `Prop` as expressed above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not provable in Coq because of the restriction on eliminating Prop into Set. As for the philosophical "meaning", I'm not sure if anyone has a very good story about this. The inhabitants of `forall n:nat, exists p:nat, P n p` are functions returning a pair of `p` and a proof, but in addition they a functions that can be ignored when compiling programs because you know that nothing will look at the value that was returned.

So partly this system of Prop versus Set is a way to compile programs more efficiently, but actually this is also used for logical properties. In Coq the Prop type is impredicative and the Set type is not, and even so it's consistent to assume the law of exluded middle for Props as an axiom, and to prove that this is consistent you can appeal to a "[proof-irrelevant model](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~werner/publis/cc.pdf)", where you interpret types in Props as sets by ignoring all information except whether they are inhabited or not. From a classical logic perspective (where all you care about are truth values) that makes sense, but if you are interested in constructive mathematics it's a bit weird!

Comment: If what I remember is correct, Prop is impredicative (in contrast, Type has universes) and so destructing Prop in computation will cause inconsistency, right?